# Implementing k stacks by three stacks

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

How is it possible to implement k stacks using only three stacks? and obviously how to implement stack functions. please provide pseudo code. thanks in advance.

Comment: if you don't have time complexity constraints, keep pairs of `(item, stack_number)` in stack 1. to push to the ith stack, push `(item, i)` to stack 1. then to pop from the kth stack, pop from stack 1 and push everything popped onto stack 2 until you see something with `stack_number==k`. then to put the stuff on stack 2 back into stack 1, to do this you pop everything and push it to stack 3, then repeat with stack 3 -> stack 1

Comment: what else if we have time constraints?

Comment: which ones? the target complexity might hint what your assignment is aiming for... If you have constraints tell us ... it is always a trade-off between time and space ...

Comment: frankly I didn't understand the role of 3rd stack in this algorithm, would you please explain me more

Comment: @Primusa why just not return all elements from second stack to the first one, after deleting? The order will be saved and we actually don't need third stack, isn't it?

Comment: @Iaroslav Sviridov I agree with you, I think 3rd stack is useless.

Comment: @IaroslavSviridov u right, i had it in my head that the order would be reversed for some reason